# Type[T] from PEP 484 for Python 3.5 typing module not implemented. How do I check for class type?

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting, pep, python-typing

So, PEP 484 has the section ["The type of class objects"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects).

On this section, it is stated that the following should be possible:

```
U = TypeVar('U', bound=User)
def new_user(user_class: Type[U]) -> U:
    user = user_class()
    # (Here we could write the user object to a database)
    return user
```

I'm just getting started on using the typing module. My problem is that when trying to find the Type hint, I just couldn't find it. It is nowhere in the source code or in the documentation.

The [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-484) indicate that the typing module implements PEP 484. There is no indication of an incomplete implementation. Is there a way to make this kind of type hint on the current version? Or is it simply impossible for now?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is up to the IDE to actually provide the functionality, PEP 484 simply gave a standard to how the type hinting should be written in code.

Comment: Currently [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) supports type hints, I'm not sure if any other IDE does.

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Type hints do nothing at runtime by design, they only exist to support static checkers

Comment: The problem here is that the `Type` generic type specified by PEP 484 doesn't seem to exist in the implementation. We're not expecting type hints to actually do anything; we're just expecting to be able to write the type hints the PEP says we can write.

Comment: I believe that section of PEP 484 was added very recently (long after the release of Python 3.5). This is an active topic of discussion on the python-dev mailing lists.

Comment: I am adding the typehints to the code and running mypy as part of the test process. Just a static check to verify the code. @Daenyth Sure, they do nothing at runtime, but if I am annotating for static checking, I would like to do it right, not a half assed effort.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The typing module provides types which are actual classes that you can put in your code. You import them, and then proceed to annotate your code.

Comment: In fact, the `Type[C]` section of PEP 484 was added just 25 hours ago: https://hg.python.org/peps/rev/e0eb77b8cd73

Comment: Wow, that recent? I didn't realize PEPs got stealth-updates like that.

Comment: @MarkDickinson wow. I didn't know that was even possible. Thank you for the response. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it. I guess that for now the best I can do is to use the type annotation instead of the generic. It is such a coincidence that I looked at the PEP when it was added so recently v.v Had I done this yesterday, I would have just gone with type and avoided waste of time. Thanks Mark.